# Change div background color with database value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I change a `<div>` background color with database value upon different dropdown selections? I consider myself doing extensive searching and have found some great information from previous posts, but not quite able to incorporate into my code.

**Here is my task**: I have a dropdown list with various temperatures. Each temp has a specific color code in the database in order to assign to the `<div>`.

e.g. 99 degrees would give me a yellow background, or 105 would give me an orange background.

**Here is current code: Dropdown menu page**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Alert Test</title>
    <meta/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    Page copy
    </p>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction_1(){
    var ajaxRequest;

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Oops! We apologize.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv_4');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var temp = document.getElementById('temp').value;
    var queryString = "?temp=" + temp;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "abc.php"+ queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
            </script>
<form>
<br />
<select id='temp'>
<option value=''>Choose Product</option>
<option value='90'>90</option>
<option value='91'>91</option>
<option value='92'>92</option>
<option value='93'>93</option>
<option value='94'>94</option>
<option value='95'>95</option>
<option value='96'>96</option>
<option value='97'>97</option>
<option value='98'>98</option>
<option value='99'>99</option>
<option value='100'>100</option>
<option value='101'>101</option>
<option value='102'>102</option>
<option value='103'>103</option>
<option value='104'>104</option>
<option value='105'>105</option>
<option value='106'>106</option>
<option value='107'>107</option>
<option value='108'>108</option>
<option value='109'>109</option>
<option value='110'>110</option>
<option value='111'>111</option>
<option value='112'>112</option>
<option value='113'>113</option>
</select>
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction_1()' value='Select' />
        </form>
            <div id='ajaxDiv_4'></div>
            </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the code calling the database**

```
<?php
include_once('conn.php');
// Retrieve data
if( isset($_GET['temp']) && $_GET['temp'] != '' ){
  $temp = $_GET['temp'];
  $temp = mysql_real_escape_string($temp);
  //query
  $query = "SELECT * FROM temps WHERE temp = '$temp'";
  //Execute
  $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    $display_string = '<strong>WARNING</strong> '.$row['alert'].'<br>';
    $display_string .= '<strong>BE AWARE</strong> '.$row['messa'].'<br>';
    $display_string .= '<strong>RESPONSE</strong> '.$row['action'].'<br>';
    $display_string .= '<br>';
  }
  echo $display_string;
} else {
  return null;
}
?>
```

Drop down and page works great. Just need some color addition to complete.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why don't you use jQuery.axjax() instead of your own implementation? You are probably still will use the jQuery lib for color picking.

Comment: Would you mind explaining further your recommendation? Thanks

Comment: well, just use jquery.ajax() instead of yours ajaxFunction_1(). jQuery handles all compatibility things for you and it is easier to handle the response in case of success or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I usually do such things is a mixture of css and jquery, I define css classes for the temprature like:

```
.temp1{background-color: red}
.temp2{background-color: blue}
```

and then after fetching the temprature, javascript and jquery does the rest with `addClass()` and `removeClass()` functions, with some logic:

```
if(temprature>90)temp=1;
else if(temprature>75)temp=2;
$('ajaxDiv_4').addClass('temp'+temp);
```

or replace the  while loop with this:

```
if($temp>100)$class = temp1;
  else if($temp>80)$class = temp2;
  else $class = temp3;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    $display_string = '<strong class='.$class.'>WARNING</strong> '.$row['alert'].'<br/>';
    $display_string .= '<strong class='.$class.'>BE AWARE</strong> '.$row['messa'].'<br/>';
    $display_string .= '<strong class='.$class.'>RESPONSE</strong> '.$row['action'].'<br/>';
    $display_string .= '<br/>';
  }
```

Comment: Awesome. Let's see if I get the appropriate placement with this.

Comment: let me know the result plz

Comment: I think I have my placement wrong. I have added the css with an external and calling it in (or so I think I am). Last I have the js/jq just below the fetch (again, so I think). Didn't work so still grinding away.

Comment: Definitely the operator here. My lack of knowledge and being a rookie with the coding is prohibitive. Still working with your addition.

Comment: That worked. Awesome. Many, Many thanks. However; it puts the color on the each header and not the entire div (hence is what your first answer was trying to do with the ajaxDiv_4). Going to see if I can still incorporate the code for the entire div.

Comment: Any further elaboration on getting the entire ajaxDiv_4 to change background color? Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making an AJAX call whenever the user changes the dropdown, it might be better to render the `option` elements with the color already known like:

```
<option value='104' data-color='yellow'>104</option>
```

Then in your click handler, you can just get the value from there.

Comment: Sounds easy and logical to me.

Comment: OK, spoke to soon. I have the option added as you have given, but what are you considering the click handler for that addition?

Comment: Either your function `ajaxFunction_1` or you could add a handler for the `change` event of the `select` element itself so the user doesn't have to click the button.